# Two taps required to make hidden UINavigationBar appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` which contains cells of different languages. When the user taps a cell, they are taken to a `UIPageViewController` which shows the appropriate leaflet in that language. That part is working well.

I have implemented the use of the following code to make the `UINavigationBar` hidden and to appear on a tap:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true;
```

I have that code in my `viewDidLoad`. I don't have any gesture recognisers, but both on the Simulator and on the device, to get the `UINavigationBar` to appear, I have to tap the screen twice. Why do I have to tap twice?

If I do the same on a `UITableViewController`, I only have to tap once, so it seems something specific about this `UIPageViewController` and I can't quite figure out what.

I've looked around and I can't seem to find anyone with anything similar.

On guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

If that does not work, can you post the code for your methods relevent to this issue?
Could probably help more with more info.

Comment: Thanks very much @Trevor - that worked like a charm - first I thought it was that line instead of the ones I had, but that didn't do anything and with the lines I had, it now goes back to a single tap! Sorry for the lack of information and methods in the question but this was a great and easy fix - I appreciate it!